# Google analytics not gathering data from .asp page

Tags: iis, asp-classic, google-analytics

I've installed [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics) several times in the past without trouble. However, recently i've installed GA on a .asp page for the first time. Google Analytics dashboard tells me the tag is properly installed, but ever after several days, i can't see any data.

---

[alt text http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/4584/tracking1.jpg](http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/4584/tracking1.jpg)

---

[alt text http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/8272/tracking2.jpg](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/8272/tracking2.jpg)

---

Is there any special setup required for .asp pages or windows servers?

Unfortunately, I don't have the option to install [GAHelper](http://gahelper.com/).

Comment: give a link to the actual  page and people can check if it's there and correct.  There are no special requirements for GA on asp pages.

Comment: Here's the site: http://dir.jp.reuters.com

Comment: Question and Solution is outdated, and not longer relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this working by using [Google Analytics Asynchronous Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html), using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
   (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
  })();

</script>
```

Never quite understood why this didn't work with the usual google tracking code...

Answer (score 1):

ASP pages should not require any special configuration. You can check if the tracking code is being outputted correctly by using View Source in your browser, that's all it takes from the server.

The next step would be using Firebug or a similar tool to see if the request to the Analytics servers is going through properly.

Comment: Have tried that without success. Firebug simply doesn't trace the usual call from the page to Google Analytics. dir.jp.reuters.com